# confusion matrix shows wrong info?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

update: attached the link to the data in case you want to reproduce:

https://github.com/amandawang-dev/credit-worthiness-analysis/blob/master/credit_train.csv

https://github.com/amandawang-dev/credit-worthiness-analysis/blob/master/credit_test.csv

I'm trying to use logistic regression model of sklearn to predict whether the person's credit of a bank account is good or bad. The initial dataset looks like below:

[image: credit worthiness data]

[image: credit worthiness continued]

---

Then I binarized the first column "Class" ('Good'=1, 'Bad'=0), and the dataset looks like below:

[image: credit worthiness data binarized]

So I used sklearn logistic model to predict the test data (test data is same as predict dataset and the 'Class' column is also binarized), and trying to calculate the confusion matrix, codes as below, then the confusion matrix I got is

```
[[  0  54]
 [  0 138]]
```

accuracy score is 0.71875, I think the confusion matrix result is wrong because there's no true positive value. Anybody have any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

credit_train = pd.read_csv('credit_train.csv')
credit_test = pd.read_csv('credit_test.csv')
credit_train["Class"] = (credit_train["Class"] =="Good").astype(int)
credit_test["Class"] = (credit_test["Class"] =="Good").astype(int)
X=credit_train[['CreditHistory.Critical']]
y=credit_train['Class']
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y)

X_test=credit_test[['CreditHistory.Critical']]
y_test=credit_test['Class']
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

cm=confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y_test)
score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(score)
print(cm)
```

---

data types of each column:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 808 entries, 0 to 807
Data columns (total 17 columns):
Class                             808 non-null int64
Duration                          808 non-null int64
Amount                            808 non-null int64
InstallmentRatePercentage         808 non-null int64
ResidenceDuration                 808 non-null int64
Age                               808 non-null int64
NumberExistingCredits             808 non-null int64
NumberPeopleMaintenance           808 non-null int64
Telephone                         808 non-null int64
ForeignWorker                     808 non-null int64
CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0        808 non-null int64
CheckingAccountStatus.0.to.200    808 non-null int64
CheckingAccountStatus.gt.200      808 non-null int64
CreditHistory.ThisBank.AllPaid    808 non-null int64
CreditHistory.PaidDuly            808 non-null int64
CreditHistory.Delay               808 non-null int64
CreditHistory.Critical            808 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(17)
memory usage: 107.4 KB
```

Comment: What is the correlation between the class and "CreditHistory.Critical"? if the correlation is low the classifier might just learn the class that is more common

Comment: Most probable that you have a serious class imbalance (much more negative samples than positive ones), rather than confusion matrix being "wrong", Class imbalance needs special handling.

Comment: can you provide a link to the data ? no one can reproduce your results without a link to the dataset.. ?

Comment: https://github.com/amandawang-dev/credit-worthiness-analysis/blob/master/credit_train.csv

Comment: https://github.com/amandawang-dev/credit-worthiness-analysis/blob/master/credit_test.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your classes are slightly imbalanced about 71% being 1:

```
credit_test["Class"].value_counts()

1    138
0     54
```

When you run a logistic regression, it estimates the mean, which is the log odds of being 1, and then the log-odds associated with your dependent variable. If you look at the coefficients:

```
[clf.intercept_,clf.coef_]
[array([0.59140229]), array([[0.9820343]])]
```

The intercept seems about correct, meaning the average is about exp(0.59140229)/(1+exp(0.59140229)) = 0.643. Your independent variable CreditHistory.Critical can only be 0 or 1, and your coefficient for that is 0.9820343 there, the outcome is always going to be p > 0.5, meaning all labels 1.

You can fit a model without an intercept, and see now the prediction is not biased, but it's basically not very accurate:

```
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0,fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y)
y_pred=clf.predict(credit_test[['CreditHistory.Critical']])
confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred, y_true=y_test)

array([[42, 12],
       [84, 54]])
```

You can try fitting the model with a few other variables to get information, it should give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, that's very helpful, one more question, "since your variable CreditHistory.Critical is also positive associated, the outcome is always going to be p > 0.5, meaning all labels 1.", for this part I don't quite get, for p>0.5, is p the probability of if x is 1 then y is 1? Also, is there any documentation/book/reference that you could recommend for what you explained so that i can read more? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AmandaWang, that part wasn't very clear. I have updated the answer. What I meant was, the coefficient for that term is positive. your response is intercept + coefficient * variable. so if intercept is positive, coefficient is positive, variables all > 0, then p > 0.5

Comment: there is a logistic regression part in https://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf .. or maybe this one, with more coding https://realpython.com/logistic-regression-python/